# TextEditingController behaviour in custom text field

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-hooks

I composed a custom text field that check the validator when it lost focus, with some UI such as error text and green checked icon. They are working fine until I need to perform some auto-filling according to other TextField's data.

When user filled up the postal code, the API will be called from ChangeNotifierProvider view model and update the state according

```
user.prefectureName = data.prefectureName;
user.city = data.city;
user.address = data.address;
notifyListeners();
```

In the HookConsumerWidget page, I passed the state into the custom text field like this

```
 OCTextField(
    text: user.prefectureName,
    labelText: l10n.accountProfileEditPrefectureName,
    errorText: "都道府県は必須項目です",
    onChanged: (value) => user.prefectureName = value,
    validator: (value) => value.isNotEmpty),
OCTextField(
    text: user.city,
    labelText: l10n.accountProfileEditCity,
    errorText: "市区町村は必須項目です",
    onChanged: (value) => user.city = value,
    validator: (value) => value.isNotEmpty),
OCTextField(
    text: user.address,
    labelText: l10n.accountProfileEditAddress,
    errorText: "丁目・番地は必須項目です",
    onChanged: (value) => user.address = value,
    validator: (value) => value.isNotEmpty),
```

[image]
However, when the state change (user.prefectureName, user.city and user.address), my custom text field won't be able to reflect the changes accordingly.
Here is part of my custom text field code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';

import '../util/ext/string_ext.dart';

typedef Validator = bool Function(String value);

class OCTextField extends HookWidget {
  const OCTextField(
      {Key? key,
      this.text = "",
      this.labelText,
      this.hintText,
      this.errorText,
      this.maxLines = 1,
      this.maxLength,
      this.sanitise = true,
      this.onChanged,
      this.validator})
      : super(key: key);

  final String text;
  final String? labelText;
  final String? hintText;
  final String? errorText;
  final int? maxLines;
  final int? maxLength;
  final bool sanitise;
  final ValueChanged<String>? onChanged;
  final Validator? validator;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _showError = useState(false);
    final _controller = useTextEditingController(text: text);
    final _checkIcon;
    final unchecked =
        const Icon(Icons.check_circle_outline, color: Colors.black26);
    final checked = const Icon(Icons.check_circle, color: Colors.green);
    if (validator != null) {
      _checkIcon = useState(validator!(_controller.text) ? checked : unchecked);
    } else {
      _checkIcon = useState(checked);
    }

    return Focus(
        child: TextField(
            controller: _controller,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(1.0),
              ),
              suffixIcon: _checkIcon.value,
              labelText: labelText,
              hintText: hintText,
              errorText: _showError.value ? errorText : null,
            ),
            maxLines: maxLines,
            maxLength: maxLength,
            onChanged: onChanged),
        onFocusChange: (isFocused) {
          if (isFocused) {
            _showError.value = false;
            _checkIcon.value = unchecked;
          } else {
            if (sanitise) {
              _controller.text = _controller.text.sanitise();
              onChanged!(_controller.text.sanitise());
            }
            if (validator != null) {
              _showError.value = !validator!(_controller.text);
            }
            _checkIcon.value = _showError.value ? unchecked : checked;
          }
        });
  }
}
```

I actually read the documentation of useTextEditingController(text: text) which it does not react to the text changes. I tried to replace `useTextEditingController` to `TextEditingController` and it somehow works, with some strange behaviour - Even I erased the reflected pre-filled text and move the another field, the text will come back again; The cursor is acting weird, when I click on the field, it starts from the beginning of the pre-fill text.

It works perfectly without strange issue when I inherited TextField class and initialise the TextControllerEditor directly into TextField instance.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class OutlinedTextField extends TextField {
  OutlinedTextField(
      {String? labelText,
      String? text,
      String? errorText,
      String? hintText,
      TextInputType keyboardType = TextInputType.text,
      int maxLines = 1,
      Icon? icon,
      List<TextInputFormatter>? inputFormatters,
      ValueChanged<String>? onChanged,
      isDense = false})
      : super(
          controller: text == null ? null : TextEditingController(text: text),
          decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(1.0),
              ),
              labelText: labelText,
              hintText: hintText,
              errorText: errorText,
              prefixIcon: icon,
              isDense: isDense),
          keyboardType: keyboardType,
          maxLines: maxLines,
          inputFormatters: inputFormatters,
          onChanged: onChanged,
        );
}
```

With this approach, I am not able to obtain the controller. The reason I am refactor the Custom Text Field with composition instead of inheritance is to access the controller.text for validation UI. Am I doing some serious mistake or misunderstanding the concept here? I am not able to figure out this strange behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. you have to add reusable controller in your custom textfield
2. Note: You have to always create a seperate controller for each textfield

```
class CustomTextField extends StatelessWidget {

// created custom controller
  TextEditingController controller;
  String text;

   CustomTextField({
    required this.controller, 
     required this.text
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField();
  }
}
```

2. then create a textEditingController for each text Filed and initilize it in oninit function.

```
late TextEditingController text1 ;
  late TextEditingController text2 ;
```

3. use the controllers in your custom text fields

```
 CustomTextField(controller: text1 ,text: "text1",),
 CustomTextField(controller: text2 ,text: "text2",)
```